# Chrome isn't loading images from cache when loading with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, httprequest, browser-cache

I have been loading images on my website using the following:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'http://i.example.com/image-1.jpg';
```

Chrome adds `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: no-cache` in the request headers.

Is there a way I can get rid of these headers or can they be modified using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

element initiates an HTTP request trying to load an image from server, so I would recommend to try using HTTP Channels to modify those headers. Try something like this:

```
httpChannel.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "new_header_state_on_your_choice_1" , false);
httpChannel.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "new_header_state_on_your_choice_2" , false);
```

Useful link about HTTP Channels: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers

If that doesn't work, have a look at the ways to intercept page (or content) loading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Intercepting_Page_Loads#HTTP_Observers

Another way is to use AJAX to literally emulate  request (AJAX request, then trying to load the response to the ), but that could be much more complicated.

P.S. There's actually HTML way to set request headers:

```
<head>   
  <meta charset="utf-8">   
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `nsIHttpChannel` isn't in Chrome. I previously tried the meta tags but they didn't work. AJAX won't work because the images are under a different sub-domain, which I forgot to include in the post. =\